# More than one launcher Activity in Android, but only one in release version

Tags: android

I read a lot of articles about how to create more than one launcher in Android applications but I would like to have two launchers, one for the launch of the application and the other to control debug options, feature flags, or whatever with the condition that this launcher is only available in debug version. I tried to move the second launcher to the manifest located in debug manifest but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: "doesn't work" is nothing we can work with. Also please edit your post and include the relevant parts of your debug manifest and in which path it is saved in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that allows me to have two launchers:

1. Main Activity which is used to launch the application as usual.
2. Catalog Activity which is used to show every ui component in the app.

The idea is that the second activity is only visible for debug variant, in other words, to be excluded from the release variant. So we need to define both activities in the AndroidManifest.xml from "main":

```
<application
    ....>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:taskAffinity="com.your.package.ui.MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.CatalogActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name_catalog"
        android:taskAffinity="com.your.package.ui.CatalogActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

And here comes the trick, define an AndroidManifest.xml in the "release" buildVariant where the second activity is removed from the merged final manifest.

```
<application>

    <activity android:name=".ui.CatalogActivity" tools:node="remove" />

</application>
```

I hope it helps.